# percentage in a complex formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, percentage, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

Need some help please

I have this formula but I want to add 2% on the total

```
={"total";ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B,N1:O,2,0)*J2:J*4))}
```

If I do like this the total is incorrect

```
={"total";ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B,N1:O,2,0)*J2:J*4+2%))}
```

I have attached a pic to be more clear.

i.e. the total showing is 24.02 but it should be 24.48

Value is 24 + 2% = 24.48

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct formula for that in Google Sheets would be:

```
=A1+(A1*2%)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi player0. Thanks a lot for that! Is there anyway we could put that in my formula so I only use one? thanks

Comment: adjusting it to my sheet it should be

={"MONTHLY";ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,DATA!A1:B,2,0)*P2:P*4+((IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,DATA!A1:B,2,0)*P2:P*4)*10%)))})

but unfortunately "Formula parse error."

It would be great to have it all in one as I am also trying to figure out how to use =Roundup(XX,-1) as well cos all values need to be multiple of 10s. I.E. 12 = 20, 43=50, etc as at the moment I have several columns so I get the final result but if not possible I will use your first response :-)
Many thanks tho

Comment: see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1okiVpGki1mXapjvkmVMpMwQCg0YeeH1sicpJDq1YJho/edit#gid=0

Comment: and see rounded: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1okiVpGki1mXapjvkmVMpMwQCg0YeeH1sicpJDq1YJho/edit#gid=1198800572

Comment: ABSOLUTELY legend. Thanks a lot!! it does work indeed